# Create CSV files and add data depending on condition php

Tags: php, loops, csv, fputcsv

I have an array of results and I want to create csv file for it. but if the result is valid I want to add the email in the valid csv file and if it is invalid then in the invalid csv file. but I am unable to do this. it adds all the emails to clean csv file and the invalid csv is empty. any suggestions

the results are looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => tamas.szabo@millionverifier.com
            [result] => valid
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [email] => support@millionverifier.com
            [result] => valid
        )

)
```

Here is my condition

```
// creating dirty and clean file
$clean_emails = fopen(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY . '/clean/' . $file_name_new . '.' . $extension, 'w');
$dirty_emails = fopen(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY . '/dirty/' . $file_name_new . '.' . $extension, 'w');

// adding headers to them
fputcsv($clean_emails, $headers);
fputcsv($dirty_emails, $headers);            

if ($results[$i]['result'] === 'valid') {

    // adding clean emails to csv
    foreach ($results as $row) {
    fputcsv($clean_emails, $row);
    }
    fclose($clean_emails);

} elseif ($results[$i]['result'] === 'invalid') {

    // adding dirty emails to csv
    foreach ($results as $row) {
    fputcsv($dirty_emails, $row);
    }
    fclose($dirty_emails);

} else {

    // if there are not any dirty or clean emails add them unknown to csv
    $unknown_emails = fopen(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY . '/unknown/' . $file_name_new . '.' . $extension, 'w');
    fputcsv($unknown_emails, $row);
    fclose($unknown_emails);

}
```

Comment: Is this condition actually in a loop?

Comment: `$results[$i]` – what is `$i` supposed to be? // Your attempt looks completely bogus to me, why are the loops _inside_ those conditionals? Should be the other way around - _one_ loop over your data, and inside of it you either write the current record to file A or file B …

Comment: `$i` is from the top loop which generates results `for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you want line-by-line separation?

```
// creating dirty and clean file
$clean_emails = fopen(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY . '/clean/' . $file_name_new . '.' . $extension, 'w');
$dirty_emails = fopen(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY . '/dirty/' . $file_name_new . '.' . $extension, 'w');
$unknown_emails = null; // No file yet

// adding headers to them
fputcsv($clean_emails, $headers);
fputcsv($dirty_emails, $headers);            

foreach ($results as $row) { // Scan each row
    if ($row['result'] === 'valid') {
        fputcsv($clean_emails, $row);
    } elseif ($row['result'] === 'invalid') {
        fputcsv($dirty_emails, $row);
    } else {  // found something else
        if (!isset($unknown_emails)) { // Open file if it was not
            $unknown_emails = fopen(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY . '/unknown/' . $file_name_new . '.' . $extension, 'w');
            fputcsv($unknown_emails, $headers); // Add headers ?
        }
        fputcsv($unknown_emails, $row);
    }
} // end loop
fclose($clean_emails);
fclose($dirty_emails);
if (isset($unknown_emails)) {
    fclose($unknown_emails); // Close 'unknown' if it was opened
}
```